# Sniffing traffic from a linux machine

Tags: linux, networking

Is there a way I can capture all the traffic incoming and outgoing from my router as a pcap to my linux machine and automate it?

edit: It's for a project where we're trying to detect threats to the network.

Comment: For a short time, or continously? How much traffic is that? 1 GB per hour? More? Less? Where do you plan to store it, and how do you plan to transfer it from your router (without generating more traffic, which also will be captured?) Do you have a dedicated computer you want to use for storing all this traffic?

Comment: Continuously,  traffic from a small medium enterprise every 5 minutes. Store it in a dedicated computer which is connected to the same network

Answer (score 3):

For something like a small medium enterprise I'd configure one port of the router to **mirror** all traffic (that is, all traffic entering through any other port gets copied to this port), then connect the dedicated capture computer to this port  and store everything to the local harddisk. This can be as simple as `tcpdump -C ...` to switch to the next capture file when a certain file size is exceeded, or more complex according to your wishes.

You should think about how long you want to retain the data, and cleanup automation.

Professional routers often come with built-in mirror capabilities; a home network type router which may be sufficient for a small medium enterprise can be reflashed with open firmware like OpenWRT, and you can use [ready-made packages](https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/port-mirroring) or configure the Linux kernel running on the router directly with `iptables` etc.

Please also consider the legal aspects: In civilized countries you'll be required to inform the employees about this kind of surveillance, in even more civilized countries it won't be allowed at all.

Comment: This is just for a proof of concept project kind of thing my friends and I are working on, so don't really have to worry about the legal issues.

But just to clarify, so, if I mirror all the traffic like that, will the mac address and the ip address will still be the same?

Comment: Even if it's a proof of concept you need to worry about the legal issues - there are countries where it's illegal to run this for an extended period of time, period, unless you are running it at home, and not in an enterprise. Whether MAC addresses are preserved depends on how the mirroring is set up.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what your goal is.

TCPdump and wireshark are 2 of tje most bandied arround tools for packet capture

"pcap" is a packet capture API rather then a file format, but typically associated with wireshark dumps.

Comment: It is in fact [a file format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat), now often generated even by non-libpcap tools. Wireshark was just one of the better known libpcap-using programs to adopt it, but it wasn't nearly the first one.

Comment: Does tcpdump work when it's just connected to the router

Comment: Yoyr question on tcpdump is unclear. TCPDump can capture sny traffic entering or leaving an interface. I routinely use it on linux based firewalls to check if the firewall is forwarding packets correctly when something that should be reachable isnt.